# Oracle Rest – filtering by columns (vertical filtering)

Tags: oracle, oracle-ords

I would like to specify in Oracle REST query which columns should be returned in the select statement.

One of the solution would be to use view, however in my case I would like to select columns in a dynamic fashion.

Such functionality is available in PostgREST: http://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/api.html#vertical-filtering-columns

Is there such feature in Oracle REST Data Services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we offer row filtering but not column selection.

So i can [say which rows I want to come back via the URI](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2019/09/some-query-filtering-examples-in-ords/), but I cannot say which columns I want.

So if you REST enable a table or view, it will be all of those columns, of it it's a RESTful Service, it will be the columns you have included in your SELECT.

Something else to keep in mind, we do have a REST Enabled SQL Feature...where [you POST your query, and we get you the results](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-rest-enabled-sql#run-query). So in the POST you could specify the columns you want.

Comment: Thank you for the link. It was very helpful. So, the only way to would be to post the whole select statement as value of "StatementText" field. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: The POST payload includes your query, you can find full Docs here at oracle.com/rest